# How to assign variable value to custom node attribute and use this value in another recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have ids and iq:

```
 bkp_id = List_volume_attached_acc.list_volume_acc('ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.adlad')
ids = bkp_id.map(&:ipv4)
iq = bkp_id.map(&:iqn)
node['ids'] = ids
```

I have to use them in another recipe (powershell script which will run on chef client). It is like this:

```
powershell_script "run-isci" do
code <<-EOH
Set-Service -Name msiscsi -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service msiscsi
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress #{node['iscsi']['ids']}
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress #{node['iscsi']['iq']} -TargetPortalAddress #{node['iscsi']['ids']} -IsPersistent $True

EOH
end
```

How can I assign values to ids and iq as node attributes so that I can use them in the second recipe?

Answer (score 0):

Given you don't seem super comfortable with complex Ruby coding, I would just copy-paste the getter code in to the other recipe too. It's pretty small and doesn't seem likely to change often so duplicating the code is probably easier than working out how to use `node.run_state`.

Comment: Sorry i am new to Ruby

Comment: That's totally okay :) It feels a little more aesthetically pleasing to only run the volume list once but when getting started I would stick to the "simple and works in all cases" method, you can refactor it in the future as you level-up your Ruby skills.

Comment: I know we can copy-paste getter code into this recipe but powershell recipe will run on remote server where values for  bkp_id = List_volume_attached_acc.list_volume_acc will not as it's dependent libraries are not present. so my getter recipe runs on chef server and powershell will run on client machine. i want to take values from 1st script and it should assign in 2nd script which will run on client machine

Comment: That is not something Chef can do.